# Differential Proving Question (Calculus)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, integration, derivatives

> If $f$ satisfies  $|f(x)|\leq |x|^9$ for all $x$ , prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

Hello I am having trouble understanding this question, could someone explain what this question is asking?

Someone was telling me that this is be a proving question, so I might need to use a theorem or something in order to prove this.

If someone could just explain this question to me step by step that would be good. No need to solve it.

THANKS !

Comment: $f$ is differentiable at $0$ if and only if $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0}$ exists.

Comment: @Tunococ, Thanks for the prompt reply !

So does that mean the above statement is not true?

Comment: @Tunococ what about $\vert x \vert^9$ isn't that just the same as saying $x^9\; , \, x>0$ ??

Comment: $|x|^9$ is not the same as $x^9$ when $x < 0$, and that matters when you consider the limit $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is $0$. To show this, use the given inequality to get $\left|\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0}\right| \le |x|^8$. As $x \to 0$, it follows that $\left|\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0}\right| \to 0$. This implies $|f'(0)| = \left|\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| = \lim_{x\to 0} \left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| = 0$. Hence, $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: Hey thanks for the great reply ! just one last question how did u get that  the limit is

 x goes to Zero